# Extend x axis on graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'd like to extend my `x` axis a little longer. Is it possible to do that?

```
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]

    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=Reynolds Number,ylabel=Coefficient Discharge]
    \addplot [color=blue,mark=*] coordinates {
        (6485.41491,0.408143397)
        (7927.942858,0.407370795)
        (8663.115504,0.38550864)
        (9219.462371,0.366953133)
        (9537.374867,0.346531912)
        (10491.11235,0.330115983)
        (11087.19828,0.312041115)
        (12219.76155,0.313951177)
    };
        \addlegendentry{1/4}
    \addplot [color=red,mark=triangle] coordinates {
        (6556.945221,   0.412644978)
        (7868.334265,   0.404307857)
        (8663.115504,   0.38550864)
        (9187.671122,   0.365687778)
        (9120.114717,   0.331371141)
        (10443.42548,   0.328615455)
        (11683.28421,   0.328817519)
        (12875.45607,   0.330797337)
    };
        \addlegendentry{1/2 Lift}
    \addplot [color=black,mark=*] coordinates {
        (6843.066467,   0.430651305)
        (8297.516134,   0.426361012)
        (9203.566747,   0.40955872)
        (8615.42863,    0.342911376)
        (9298.940495,   0.337868614)
        (10824.92047,   0.340619673)
        (11683.28421,   0.328817519)
        (12899.29951,   0.331409925)
    };
        \addlegendentry{3/4 Lift}
    \addplot [color=yellow,mark=*] coordinates {
        (6854.988186,   0.431401568)
        (8398.850742,   0.431568008)
        (9267.149246,   0.412388141)
        (8567.741755,   0.341013343)
        (9346.62737 ,   0.339601273)
        (10753.39016,   0.338368882)
        (11897.87515,   0.334857025)
        (13030.43841,   0.334779157)
    };
        \addlegendentry{Full Lift}
    \end{axis}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

[image]

Comment: How much is "a little"? Up until 1.6, 1.8, 2? And to the right or also left? Do you want to keep the same ratio of the graph sides? Also, please include all the code necessary to compile the document with your results, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: @user127841, Just some remark on content: it is very rare, that curves like this "travel backwards". I.e. the yellow and black data seem to have some trouble, and to some degree the red one, too. // Perhaps the line connectors reflect the sequence of measurements? Still, it would be better to drop lines at all (sequence is no relevant piece of information - think of "repeat and reproduce", by anyone, anywhere, anytime). Instead, measurement error IS relevant information, which can aslo be visualized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming (based on guessing of course...) that your document is two column article. To make graph that not be square but rectangle, is (to my opinion) sufficient to select appropriate width and height of graph:

[image]

Image above has ration 4:3, generated is by the following code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}                 % only for test, in real document must be deleted

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14,           % <-- added
            width=\columnwidth,     % <-- added
            height=0.75\columnwidth % <-- added, with this the image is in aspect 4:3
            }

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]

  \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=Reynolds Number,
    ylabel=Coefficient Discharge,
    legend style={cells={anchor=west}}      % <-- added
                ]

\addplot [color=blue,mark=*] coordinates {
    (6485.41491,0.408143397)
    (7927.942858,0.407370795)
    (8663.115504,0.38550864)
    (9219.462371,0.366953133)
    (9537.374867,0.346531912)
    (10491.11235,0.330115983)
    (11087.19828,0.312041115)
    (12219.76155,0.313951177)
};
    \addlegendentry{1/4}
\addplot [color=red,mark=triangle] coordinates {
    (6556.945221,   0.412644978)
    (7868.334265,   0.404307857)
    (8663.115504,   0.38550864)
    (9187.671122,   0.365687778)
    (9120.114717,   0.331371141)
    (10443.42548,   0.328615455)
    (11683.28421,   0.328817519)
    (12875.45607,   0.330797337)
};
    \addlegendentry{1/2 Lift}
\addplot [color=black,mark=*] coordinates {
    (6843.066467,   0.430651305)
    (8297.516134,   0.426361012)
    (9203.566747,   0.40955872)
    (8615.42863,    0.342911376)
    (9298.940495,   0.337868614)
    (10824.92047,   0.340619673)
    (11683.28421,   0.328817519)
    (12899.29951,   0.331409925)
};
    \addlegendentry{3/4 Lift}
\addplot [color=yellow,mark=*] coordinates {
    (6854.988186,   0.431401568)
    (8398.850742,   0.431568008)
    (9267.149246,   0.412388141)
    (8567.741755,   0.341013343)
    (9346.62737 ,   0.339601273)
    (10753.39016,   0.338368882)
    (11897.87515,   0.334857025)
    (13030.43841,   0.334779157)
};
    \addlegendentry{Full Lift}
\end{axis}%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I delete `scale` option. It can become an evil. Better is define image size in advance. and left to `pgfplots` to accommodate graphs to prescribed size.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using pgfplots, try adding `xmin=...` and / or `xmax=...` to the axis environment's options. Here is an example using your code (I added the necessary code to make the example compile):

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]

\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=Reynolds Number,ylabel=Coefficient Discharge,xmin=500,xmax=18000]
\addplot [color=blue,mark=*] coordinates {
    (6485.41491,0.408143397)
    (7927.942858,0.407370795)
    (8663.115504,0.38550864)
    (9219.462371,0.366953133)
    (9537.374867,0.346531912)
    (10491.11235,0.330115983)
    (11087.19828,0.312041115)
    (12219.76155,0.313951177)
};
    \addlegendentry{1/4}
\addplot [color=red,mark=triangle] coordinates {
    (6556.945221,   0.412644978)
    (7868.334265,   0.404307857)
    (8663.115504,   0.38550864)
    (9187.671122,   0.365687778)
    (9120.114717,   0.331371141)
    (10443.42548,   0.328615455)
    (11683.28421,   0.328817519)
    (12875.45607,   0.330797337)
};
    \addlegendentry{1/2 Lift}
\addplot [color=black,mark=*] coordinates {
    (6843.066467,   0.430651305)
    (8297.516134,   0.426361012)
    (9203.566747,   0.40955872)
    (8615.42863,    0.342911376)
    (9298.940495,   0.337868614)
    (10824.92047,   0.340619673)
    (11683.28421,   0.328817519)
    (12899.29951,   0.331409925)
};
    \addlegendentry{3/4 Lift}
\addplot [color=yellow,mark=*] coordinates {
    (6854.988186,   0.431401568)
    (8398.850742,   0.431568008)
    (9267.149246,   0.412388141)
    (8567.741755,   0.341013343)
    (9346.62737 ,   0.339601273)
    (10753.39016,   0.338368882)
    (11897.87515,   0.334857025)
    (13030.43841,   0.334779157)
};
    \addlegendentry{Full Lift}
\end{axis}%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my file I just used width and height, which can be adjusted according to your requirement

```
 \pgfplotsset{
  width= 360,
  height= 170
  }
```

Take a look in this example.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
width= 360,
height= 170
}
\begin{axis} [ 
title={Deployment to the Etherium},
xlabel={Attempts},
ylabel={Time [in seconds]},
xmin=0, xmax=20,
ymin=0, ymax=35,
xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20},
ytick={0,5,10,15,20,25, 30, 35},
legend pos=north west,
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
color=blue,
mark=square,
]
coordinates {
(1,5)(2,25)(3,15)(4,35)(5,30)(6,15)(7,10)(8,25)(9,15)(10,35)(11,5)(12,15)(13,10)(14,20)(15,25)(16,30)(17,10)(18,20)(19,25)(20,15)
};
\legend{$L_1$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```