# Extending x axis longer

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

Possible to extend x axis longer so graph is more like a rectangular box? More of changing the width size rather than the actual axis?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]

\begin{axis}[

    xlabel=Reynolds Number,ylabel=Coefficient Discharge]
\addplot [color=blue,mark=*] coordinates {
    (6485.41491,0.408143397)
    (7927.942858,0.407370795)
    (8663.115504,0.38550864)
    (9219.462371,0.366953133)
    (9537.374867,0.346531912)
    (10491.11235,0.330115983)
    (11087.19828,0.312041115)
    (12219.76155,0.313951177)
};
    \addlegendentry{1/4}
\addplot [color=red,mark=triangle] coordinates {
    (6556.945221,   0.412644978)
    (7868.334265,   0.404307857)
    (8663.115504,   0.38550864)
    (9187.671122,   0.365687778)
    (9120.114717,   0.331371141)
    (10443.42548,   0.328615455)
    (11683.28421,   0.328817519)
    (12875.45607,   0.330797337)
};
    \addlegendentry{1/2 Lift}
\addplot [color=black,mark=*] coordinates {
    (6843.066467,   0.430651305)
    (8297.516134,   0.426361012)
    (9203.566747,   0.40955872)
    (8615.42863,    0.342911376)
    (9298.940495,   0.337868614)
    (10824.92047,   0.340619673)
    (11683.28421,   0.328817519)
    (12899.29951,   0.331409925)
};
    \addlegendentry{3/4 Lift}
\addplot [color=yellow,mark=*] coordinates {
    (6854.988186,   0.431401568)
    (8398.850742,   0.431568008)
    (9267.149246,   0.412388141)
    (8567.741755,   0.341013343)
    (9346.62737 ,   0.339601273)
    (10753.39016,   0.338368882)
    (11897.87515,   0.334857025)
    (13030.43841,   0.334779157)
};
    \addlegendentry{Full Lift}
\end{axis}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

[image]

Comment: in what way is this question different to your previous one http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358876/extend-x-axis-on-graph ?

Comment: Have you had a look in the manual of pgfplots? You can specify the width and height in the options of the axis, where you already define xlabel and so on.